# How do I setup my cloud-init instance to fully conform to that of amazon-ec2 platform?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-init

How do I setup my cloud-init instance to fully conform to that of amazon-ec2 platform? (shown @ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)

We already made the necessary configurations as instructed for ec2, but some end points with more specific /latest/meta-data/public-keys/0/openssh-key/

Seems to be unexpected and it uses /latest/meta-data/public-keys/ to actually build up the keys.

Anyone have any experience in this specific problem?